# Flask app not able to run on gunicorn because of threading

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, gunicorn

I am completely new to Gunicorn and I am trying to run my Flask app on Gunicorn. The error I encountered can be replicated as follows.

```
import threading
from flask import Flask

def perpectual_background_process():
    while True:
        True

def start_background_thread():
    global extra_thread
    extra_thread = threading.Thread(target=perpectual_background_process)
    extra_thread.start()

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return str(extra_thread.is_alive())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_background_thread()
    app.run()
```

The browser would correctly show `True` when the app is running on a Flask server, but returns the following error when running on a Gunicorn server.

```
➜ app_folder gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000 app:app
[2024-01-24 22:05:11 +0800] [65632] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
[2024-01-24 22:05:11 +0800] [65632] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (65632)
[2024-01-24 22:05:11 +0800] [65632] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2024-01-24 22:05:11 +0800] [65634] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 65634
[2024-01-24 22:05:15,612] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2528, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1825, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1823, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "/Users/my_name/Downloads/testing/app.py", line 17, in hello_world
    return str(extra_thread.is_alive())
NameError: name 'extra_thread' is not defined
```

Seems like the app is unable to start the `extra_thread` before `app`. I have done some researches but I am unable to find or come up with a solution to deal with this. How do I get my app to operate as desired? Thank you very much for your time and help!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to define the `extra_thread` in the global scope as the `global` keyword just references existing variables, but does not define them.:

```
...

extra_thread = None

def start_background_thread():
    global extra_thread
    ...

...
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped me to solve the problem. Would you mind further explain the difference between your answer and simply removing ```if __name__ == '__main__':``` from the app.py?